# How to compute equal-frequency bins in Qlik Sense?

Tags: machine-learning, business-intelligence, binning, qliksense

I can find `class` function by which I am able to do classes in absolute terms. I could use it if I could scale values between `0` and `1`, for example with softmax function, unfortunately haven't yet found in Qlik.

**How can I compute equal-frequency bins in Qlik Sense?**